# Unreal Engine: Area becomes lit after building the project, without any actual lighting

Tags: lighting, unreal-engine4

I'm currently learning UE4 basis from the Unreal Engine YouTube channel.
In this particular blueprint tutorial a Trigger Box is used so that whenever an actor goes inside a small room, a PointLight is lit after 0.5 secs delay. 
As long as I DON'T build the project, everything works just fine: the room is pitch dark, I go inside, light turns on, I go outside, light turns off. But after building the project the whole room is slightly lit for no reason. 
The PointLight blueprint script still works, but the room isn't dark anymore. I literally followed step by step the video (and actually you can notice he never builds the project) [This is the video I'm talking about](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gHdwOiR0D0A&list=PLZlv_N0_O1gY35ezlSQn1sWOGfh4C7ewO&index=3)

The only way I have to make it work properly again is to delete the PointLight Actor, build the lightning, create a new PointLight Actor, add it to the Blueprint Script and NOT build the project.

Comment: try something around cast shadow topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete any diractional light object you might have on your map, even if its set to 0 it creates a lightmass volume which makes light bounce off of objects and light up the entire scene